# Pasting Values in SQL Query through R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have the following dataframe which contains the AxiomaID.

```
x<-c(0123, 234, 2348, 345, 3454)
```

And trying to run the following SQL Query within R.

```
 SQL6<-data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, "SELECT top 10 [AxiomaDate] 
  ,[RiskModelID]
  ,[AxiomaID]
  ,[Factor1]
   FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma].[SecurityExposures]
   Where AxiomaID = x"))
```

How can I paste all the x values which contain the AxiomaID's into the SQL Query?

Comment: Did u get any error? If yes than please mention it in your question. That'll be really helpful.

Comment: the SQL query in R reads x as x since the query is in quotation.  42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'x'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SQL6<-data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, paste("SELECT top 10 [AxiomaDate] 
  ,[RiskModelID]
  ,[AxiomaID]
  ,[Factor1]
   FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma].[SecurityExposures]
   Where AxiomaID IN (", paste(x, collapse = ", "), ")")))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not quite - the AxiomaID in x needs to be in ''. So the first value goes into the query as '0123' and not 0123 as it does currently. Is there an easy way to add '' for all the AxiomaID? Note I have many more IDs so the more automated the better!

Comment: Ok. Let me try then

Comment: do you want it like this: where AxiomaID IN ('0123','234'...) ?

Comment: Yes is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: then I think you should save values in vectors as string instead of numbers. Like x<- c("0123","234"...)

Comment: Okay but because I have a large set of numbers is there a way I can do this that is not manual?

Comment: how did u get this vector intially?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155230/discussion-between-harshil-and-user8491385).

Answer (score 0):

You would try a function like

```
InsertListInQuery <- function(querySentence, InList) {
  InValues <- ""
for (i in 1:length(InList)){
  if (i < length(InList)) {
    InValues <- paste(InValues,InList[[i]],",")}
  else {
    InValues <- paste(InValues,InList[[i]],sep = "")
  }

}
  LocOpenParenthesis <- gregexpr('[(]', querySentence)[[1]][[1]]
  LocCloseParenthesis <- gregexpr('[)]', querySentence)[[1]][[1]]
  if (LocCloseParenthesis-LocOpenParenthesis==1) {
    querySentence<- gsub("[(]", paste("(",InValues,sep = ""), querySentence)
  }
 return (querySentence )
}
```

Function InsertListInQuery requires you to change your original query to one that use constraint IN () in WHERE clausule. What function does is to conform a string with vector elements separated by comma, and replace "(" string with the one composed. Finally, return a character variable.
Hence, you can define your vector of constraints list of elements, your query and call the function as shown:

```
x<-c(0123, 234, 2348, 345, 3454)
query <- "SELECT top 10 [AxiomaDate] 
  ,[RiskModelID]
,[AxiomaID]
,[Factor1]
FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma].[SecurityExposures]
Where AxiomaID IN ()"
finalQuery <- InsertListInQuery(query, x)
```

Value of finalQuery is:

```
finalQuery
[1] "SELECT top 10 [AxiomaDate] \n  ,[RiskModelID]\n,[AxiomaID]\n,[Factor1]\nFROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma].[SecurityExposures]\nWhere AxiomaID IN ( 123 , 234 , 2348 , 345 ,3454)"
```

Note the line return with special character \n.

I hope it may help.