# Pasting data to SQL Query

Tags: r

This is driving me pretty nuts but cannot get it to work.

I want to paste the following into a SQL query within R.

```
UKWinnersID<-c("'1WKX6'", "'ULTY8'", "'JNZX0'", "'8J4D8'", 
"'KZJAJ0'", "'W8BH47'", "'CP8RPW9'", "'52TD5'", "'TLKV4'")



sqlQuery(myConn, paste("SELECT TOP 10000 [AxiomaDate]
                      ,[RiskModelID] ,[AxiomaID],[Factor1],[Factor2],[Factor3]
                      FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma]
                     Where  AxiomaID IN (",(paste(UKWinnersID, collapse = ","),")")))
```

I am using the paste function now which doesn't seem to work. Anyone got an idea? The input for the last line would be like this (with the data stored in a) for the query to work..

```
AxiomaID IN ('1WKX6', 'ULTY8', 'JNZX0', '8J4D8', 
'KZJAJ0', 'W8BH47', 'CP8RPW9', '52TD5', 'TLKV4')
```

The current output is

sqlQuery etc Where AxiomaID IN ( '1WKX6','ULTY8','JNZX0','8J4D8','KZJAJ0','W8BH47','CP8RPW9','52TD5','TLKV4' )'"

Essentially I want to remove the last two characters in this paste which is a ' and ".

Comment: try using `paste(UKWinnersID, collapse = ",")` instead of `print`.

Comment: This gets me close but not quite there - please see updated question above. I essentially need to remove the last two characters for the query to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to recreate your exact output.  Try the following; it produces the SQL code I would expect.

```
UKWinnersID<-c("'1WKX6'", "'ULTY8'", "'JNZX0'", "'8J4D8'", 
               "'KZJAJ0'", "'W8BH47'", "'CP8RPW9'", "'52TD5'", "'TLKV4'")

sqlQuery(myConn, paste("SELECT TOP 10000 [AxiomaDate]
                      ,[RiskModelID] ,[AxiomaID],[Factor1],[Factor2],[Factor3]
                       FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma]
                       Where  AxiomaID IN (",paste(UKWinnersID, collapse = ","),")"))
```

Comment: Now my output is closer but there is still one ' at the end outside the bracket as : sqlQuery etc Where AxiomaID IN ( '1WKX6','ULTY8','JNZX0','8J4D8','KZJAJ0','W8BH47','CP8RPW9','52TD5','TLKV4'  )'

Answer (score 0):

I recommended a solution to a similar question. see [Pasting Values in SQL Query through R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46588938/7008664)

You could try defining a character variable with the query value. Then you can call function InsertListInQuery passing query and vector as it arguments as follow:

```
UKWinnersID<-c("'1WKX6'", "'ULTY8'", "'JNZX0'", "'8J4D8'", 
               "'KZJAJ0'", "'W8BH47'", "'CP8RPW9'", "'52TD5'", "'TLKV4'")

query <- "SELECT TOP 10000 [AxiomaDate]
                      ,[RiskModelID] ,[AxiomaID],[Factor1],[Factor2],[Factor3]
                      FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma]
                     Where  AxiomaID IN ()"

SQLQuery <- InsertListInQuery(query, UKWinnersID)

SQLQuery
[1] "SELECT TOP 10000 [AxiomaDate]\n,[RiskModelID] ,[AxiomaID],[Factor1],[Factor2],[Factor3]\nFROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma]\nWhere  AxiomaID IN ( '1WKX6' , 'ULTY8' , 'JNZX0' , '8J4D8' , 'KZJAJ0' , 'W8BH47' , 'CP8RPW9' , '52TD5' ,'TLKV4')"
```

I hope it helps.